# Why is Spring JPA looking for dtype when I use an Embeddable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Why is hibernate looking for a discriminator column when using Embeddables?

I'm not sure if I'm doing this the best way. I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.1. I have a couple of tables that have columns in common. I want the columns in the table but I want to be able to standardize the columns across tables. More like an interface than inheriting a class.

I almost having things working but I'm getting an error of  column "dtype" of relation "user_account" does not exist. There is some other inheritance that I included but everything was working until I added the Embedded fields.

In this example I have a street address used in multiple tables, and in some cases multiple times in the same table.

StreetAddress

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class StreetAddress {
    public String addressLine1;
    public String addressLine2,
    public String city,
    public String state,
    public String zipcode
}
```

UserAccountBase (this is eventually extended by UserAccount and extends a base class has common UUID fields for the ID)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class UserAccountBase extends UUIDBase implements Person {
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
   
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride( name = "addressLine1", column = @Column(name = "mailing_address_line_1")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "addressLine2", column = @Column(name = "mailing_address_line_2")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "city", column = @Column(name = "mailing_city")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "state", column = @Column(name = "mailing_state")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "zipcode", column = @Column(name = "mailing_zipcode")),
    })
    private StreetAddress mailingAddress;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride( name = "addressLine1", column = @Column(name = "billing_address_line_1")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "addressLine2", column = @Column(name = "billing_address_line_2")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "city", column = @Column(name = "billing_city")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "state", column = @Column(name = "billing_state")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "zipcode", column = @Column(name = "billing_zipcode")),
    })
    private StreetAddress billingAddress;

}
```

I don't want to have an address table, I want the data in the related entity. I'm not sure why it's even looking for a dtype column in this case.

How do I get rid of the error or is there a better way of accomplishing this?